# Pyspark dataframe joins with few duplicated column names and few without duplicate columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I need to implement pyspark dataframe joins in my project.

I need to join in 3 different cases.

1)
If both dataframes have same name join columns. I joined as below. It eliminated duplicate columns `col1, col2`.

```
cond = ['col1', 'col2']

df1.join(df2, cond, "inner")
```

2) If both dataframes have different name join columns. I joined as below. It maintains all `4` join columns as expected.

```
cond = [df1.col_x == df2.col_y,
        df1.col_a == df2.col_b]

df1.join(df2, cond, "inner")
```

3) If dataframes have few same name join columns and few different name join columns. I tried as below. But, it is failing.

```
cond = [df1.col_x == df2.col_y,
        df1.col_a == df2.col_b,
        'col1',
        'col2',
        'col3']

df1.join(df2, cond, "inner")
```

I tried as below which worked.

```
cond = [df1.col_x == df2.col_y,
        df1.col_a == df2.col_b,
        df1.col1 == df2.col1,
        df1.col2 == df2.col2,
        df1.col3 == df2.col3]

df1.join(df2, cond, "inner")
```

But `col1, col2, col3` have duplicate columns. I want to eliminate these duplicate columns while joining itself instead of `drop` the columns later.

Please suggest how #3 can be achieved or suggest alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do it: behind the scenes an equi-join (`colA == colB`) where the condition is given as a (sequence of) string(s) (which is called a natural join) is executed as if it were a regular equi-join ([source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/4193d2f4cc2bb100625b073e3a2e8599c3b4cb7c/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/Analyzer.scala#L2638-L2686)) so

```py
frame1.join(frame2, 
            "shared_column",
            "inner")
```

gets translated to

```py
frame1.join(frame2,
            frame1.shared_column == frame2.shared_column, 
            "inner")
```

Afterwards, the duplicate gets dropped (projection).

If you have a condition that uses both keys that could be a natural join as well as a regular equi-join, then either drop the duplicate columns afterwards, or rename the ones that are not equally named before the join.